# Is it okay to cancel Visual Studio installation? And can I resume it?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'am currently installing Visual Studio 2013. It takes 2 hour and not yet finished. The process seems stuck on `Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0`, it's not going further at all.

So, is it okay to cancel it? I mean, will there something broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can take up to 4 hours to install, also clicking cancel will cause the installer to roll back the previous changes, which can take 2+ hours. I would recommend leaving it to do its thing, and going to watch a movie or something in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

MS installs are always difficult to repair and typically conflict with prior versions very easily.  That being said, you won't know until you try.  If you encounter any problems, simply uninstall VS and reinstall or use the wizard repair feature.